# Extract a matching substring in a python string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a substring from a large string that matches my pattern.

```
text = 'This is a large subsring. bla bla bla AND www.dumbweb.com/Dumbo and www.otherLinks.com...'

pattern = 'dumbweb.com'
```

here i'm trying to find the string that matches `pattern`

```
theLink = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(theLink)  //output: dumbweb.com
```

but i'm only able to find the exact text that i'm searching with, i'm trying to get the full string split by space

desired output:

```
theLink //www.dumbweb.com/Dumbo
```

i tired searching for similar question but i'm not able to phrase it right, i even looked up the Python Regex still not able to achieve what i'm looking for.

Comment: You literally mentioned split by space, so try: `print([k for k in text.split() if 'dumbweb.com' in k])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider this approach:

```sh
import re
text = 'This is a large subsring. bla bla bla AND www.dumbweb.com/Dumbo and www.otherLinks.com...'
pattern = 'dumbweb.com'

rex = re.compile(r'\b' + r'\S*' + re.escape(pattern) + r'\S*')
print (rex.findall(text))
```

**Output:**

```
['dumbweb.com/Dumbo']
```

**Explanation:**

- `re.compile(...)`: compiles a given string regex pattern
- `r'\b'`: Word boundary
- `r'\S*'`: Match 0 or more non-whitespace characters
- `re.escape(pattern)`: Perform regex escape of the given string
- `r'\S*'`: Match 0 or more non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
[^ ]*dumbweb\.com[^ ]*
```

Note that in regex a `.` matches any character. You need to use `\.` to match only a literal period

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should be

```
pattern = "www\.dumbweb\.com[^\\s]*"
```

This will print the link starting from [www.dumbweb.com](http://www.dumbweb.com) until there's a trailing space

Comment: This will also match `wwwwdumbweb$com`

Comment: can you please check my new answer, is it fine?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.search('dumbweb.com[\S]*', text).group() 
# matches your string followed by any character but white space
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the cleanest solution:

```html
text = 'This is a large subsring. bla bla bla AND www.dumbweb.com/Dumbo and www.otherLinks.com...'

pattern = 'dumbweb.com'

for word in text.split():
    if word.find(pattern) > 0:
        print(word)
```